# How to force User Style Sheet to ovewrite all the elements style in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, styles

I have the following style sheet to for the color and background :

```
*
{
    color: #000 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: #d0d0d0 !important;        
}
```

But still this is not being applied to all elements at times, for example https://math.stackexchange.com/ there is still a big white background in the middle.

What needs to be done just to have one color background for all the elements?

I have only tried this with internet exploprer 9.

Comment: I see no error in your CSS. I just tried it myself, and did not see a white background: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ7EZ.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ7EZ.png)

Comment: @iglvzx : all was needed was a restart of IE, now all is as was expected.

Comment: Great! I will post a community wiki with this notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no errors in your CSS, you may have to [restart Internet Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/425029/how-to-force-user-style-sheet-to-ovewrite-all-the-elements-style-in-internet-exp#comment487375_425029) before the styles are applied properly.